# Animation move step by step in Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have to create a animation in Unity. The animation is same as character in Mummy Maze (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GR3LlbRKf5w).

I hope that the animation will move step by step as the Mummy Maze Game.

Now, I use function

```
/*targetPosition: position which character will be moved to*/
void Move(Vector3 targetPosition){
    this.transform.position = targetPosition;
}
```

but It look like teleport. It is not moving naturally.

How to help me to my character move step by step to target position naturally without looking like teleport. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [Update](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) pattern to move the mummy each frame.

public float MoveSpeed = 1; // change this in the inspector to change how fast the mummy moves

```
Vector3 targetPosition;

void Move(Vector3 targetPosition)
{
    this.targetPosition = targetPosition;
}

void Update()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Thank Formic, i have to try your suggestion. Right now, I know your idea. I am new in Unity, so i would like to ask you another question:

How to call multi frames when I click mouse or press a button?

Now, i catch event mouse or button on Update() function. So when i press button one time, my character only moves a short distance. I need to press button some times so that my character can move to position which i want.

How to my character move to target position with one pressing button?

Thanks you a lot. (Please look at my under code )

Comment: Hey, you really should mark this your question as answered, and then ask your other question as a new question rather than creating a never ending thread.

Comment: Thanks Formic, It is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Formic, i have to try your suggestion. Right now, I know your idea. I am new in Unity, so i would like to ask you another question:

How to call multi frames when I click mouse or press a button?

Now, i catch event mouse or button on Update() function. So when i press button one time, my character only moves a short distance. I need to press button some times so that my character can move to position which i want.

How to my character move to target position with one pressing button? Thanks you a lot. (Please look at my under code )

```
public float MoveSpeed = 5.0f;
public float Step = 1.0f; //character move one cell one times - distance cells is 1.0f


void Update()
{
     if (Input.GetKeyUp ("d")) {
         float targetPos = this.transform.position.x + Step; //currentX + Step 
         Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(targetPos, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);

         Move(targetPosition); //call to move
     }
}

void Move(Vector3 targetPosition)
{
     transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```